# Recursive message definition in ROS2

Tags: ros, ros2, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is it possible to create a recursive message type in ROS2?  E.g.:
message Node.msg
int64 id
my_msgs/Node neighbors

This is currently causing compiler errors in ROS2 Humble for me but I was wondering if there was a flag or something I could use?

For more context, I'm working on writing a protobuf to ROS converter (which has generally been straightforward).  However protobuf allows recursive messages and message loops (e.g. message A references message B which references message A).  Figuring out a ROS equivalent to this if ROS doesn't allow recursive messages is going to be tricky!

Thanks!
-Jenny

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411194/recursive-message-definition-in-ros2/) by [jbarry](https://answers.ros.org/users/486/jbarry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 280 on 2023-01-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No. It is not possible, sorry. I made the same question here:

https://github.com/ros2/rosidl_typesupport/issues/128

---

Originally posted by [fmrico](https://answers.ros.org/users/13346/fmrico/) with karma: 85 on 2023-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbarry](https://answers.ros.org/users/486/jbarry/) on 2023-01-10**:
Ah thanks!  I googled a bunch but didn't find that.  I wonder if pointing out that that solution isn't good for message loops would increase its likelihood of being added someday...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

To my understanding message definitions are used to generate POD structures.
A recursive definition would generate an infinite structure, e.g. in C++ :

```
struct Node
{
  Node neighbor;
};
```

Note that an array of Node should do the trick but it seems it does not compile either, though the C++ version is fine:

```
struct Node
{
  std::vector<Node> neighbors;
};
```

In your case one could suggest an array of id's to represent the neighbors of the node.

---

Originally posted by [Olivier Kermorgant](https://answers.ros.org/users/11856/olivier-kermorgant/) with karma: 280 on 2023-01-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbarry](https://answers.ros.org/users/486/jbarry/) on 2023-01-10**:
Unfortunately this doesn't help in my case.  I'm writing a tool to automatically convert protobuf messages to ROS messages.  I don't know the content of the messages ahead of time and can't change it.  Protobuf allows recursive message definitions (presumably their implemention involves pointers for C++) but ROS messages with recursive definitions don't compile because they appear not to be able to forward declare.  I can work around this using byte strings but if there's a way to tell the compiler to forward declare the message type that would be easier.